# Using joins rather than subqueries

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have a mysql database containing two tables - **[PM_text]** and **[PM_bact]**, among others. The two tables contain one common data column. My intention is to retrieve information from the first table using matches to the common data column from the second table. I initially used a nested query for this and it had worked okay. I suddenly noticed that it does not execute conclusively any more. I want to use 'joins' instead, to see if that would optimize it further.

This is my initial query:

**SELECT pmid, year, title, pages FROM PM_text WHERE pmid IN (SELECT pmd_id from PM_bact WHERE bact1 LIKE ? AND bact2 LIKE ? AND associat LIKE ?);**

But I intend to change that to:

**SELECT DISTINCT PM_text.pmid, PM_text.year, PM_text.title, PM_text.pages FROM PM_text, PM_bact WHERE PM_text.pmid = PM_bact.pmd_id AND PM_bact.bact1 LIKE ? AND PM_bact.bact2 LIKE ? AND PM_bact.associat LIKE ? ;**

I need to ensure matches to 'bact1', 'bact2' and 'associat' in the second table and am concerned that the repeated use of 'AND' in the query might affect its optimization.

I am sure that there are better ways of doing this and being new to the subject I would appreciate any help you can render. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *it does not execute conclusively*? Is `PM_bact.pmd_id` nullable?

Comment: Btw, you should use the code formatting as I provided and not bolding when showing code.

Comment: It hangs and would not return any edits no matter how long one waited for it to finish

Comment: OK Thomas. This is actually my first post here. Will correct that in subsequent posts. Thanks

Comment: If it is purely a performance issue, you will need to present the explain plan results.

Comment: You should look into http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html to find out what the db is actually doing. Maybe you didn't use an index on a table or something.

Comment: No @Thomas. neither PM_text.pmid nor PM_bact.pmd_id is nullable

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is fine, Nothing wrong with lots of and statements. Make sure you have indexes on pmid and pmd_id columns and you should see fine performance for this.

You could write it out, fully spelling out inner joins with on clauses, but the query will execute the same as you have it now.

Comment: In second query `PM_text.pmid = PM_bact.pmd_id` would take more time to load data? Can we apply some other approach?

Comment: @SatishPandey - I don't think I understand what you are asking. Take more time to load than what? Joining on indexed fields should be one of the fastest possible ways to filter data.

Comment: @invertedSpear, Thanks very much for the answer. I will implement your advice and report back. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Satish Pandey, thanks also for your input. I will report back when I implement the advice, so we see how better it works. Thanks